# SAP RFC CALL FROM OLE Object

Tags: com, ole, saprfc

I am making a Sap interface I am using COM / OLE objects I do not know about SAP but the person who I am working with has a little experience.

He says that import answer has a lot of information and I should get it from my code but when I check imports parameters I just get a structure, there are not tables in rfc answer

He says that when RFC is run from SAP GUI It returns a table but when I call it from COM /OLE there are not

Does import structure have information? Should rfc return a table with information? Is there something missing in RFC answer?

I hope somebody can explain me how a RFC works because I think rfc needs something else to work.

Comment: Could you please describe in detail what you did so far -- especially which RFC function module you're trying to call -- and what exactly the problem is? In its current form, the question can't really be answered...

Answer (score 1):

The OLE object that represents the RFC- function (lets call it `rfcFuncObject`) has a member `tables`. e.g.:

```
Object rfcFuncObject = functionCtrl.Add("RFC_CUSTOMER_GET")
Object rfcTable = theFunc.tables

Object customerItem = rfcTable.Item("CUSTOMER_T")
```

See a complete example at [help.sap.com](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/40/b297fcc32711d194ac00a0c94260a5/content.htm)